# Create a GeoDataFrame with all the countries in the world with osmnx, efficiently

Tags: python, osmnx

I'm trying to create a GeoDataFrame with the names and geometries of all 195 countries in the world.

My attempt was to create a rectangle covering the entire world, and then query it with osmnx.

```
gdf_countries = osmnx.geometries_from_polygon(sh_roi, tags={'place': 'country'})
```

where `sh_roi` is a rectangular shapely polygon encompassing the whole world.
This takes of course too long to be feasible (I stopped after a day), and I am wondering if there are better options.

Answer (score 2):

#### tl;dr

```
import geopandas as gpd

gdf = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
```

#### description

A dataframe with all the 195 countries geometries can be found without using osmnx, thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63516948/how-to-convert-shapefile-geojson-to-hexagons-using-uber-h3-in-python) answer.

It is enough to load one of the datasets embedded in geopandas:

```
import geopandas as gpd

gdf = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
```

Now:

```
gdf.head()
```

[image: head of the dataframe with all the countries]

Then to add new values, and visualise the map:

```
gdf['gdp_md_per_capita'] = gdf['gdp_md_est'].div(gdf['pop_est'])

ax = gdf.plot(figsize=(15, 15), column='gdp_md_per_capita', cmap='RdBu')
ax.axis('off')
```

[image: Plot of all the countries and their gdp]